# npm app-store-scraper package: why this javascript object is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, web-scraping, app-store

I'm just trying to scrape only 'title' by using npm app-store-scraper package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-store-scraper

I already installed the package and from the sample code, I could get the object.

[object structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpqh6.png)

As you can see the output, variable 'data' is object, but when I tried to get the first one as an example, type of data[0] shows 'undefined'.

And when I input below code:

console.log(Object.keys(data).length);

its output is 0.

How can I scrape only titles from the scraped data by using this package module?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you defining data? From the looks of that piece of code in your image it's a Promise waiting to be resolved. How to use `app-store-scraper` is explained on its page. If you are doing `var data = store.app({id: 553834731})` and log it in the next line, it's not going to work.

Comment: I want to use 'search' module because I want to get the results from a query.  I defined data like this

Comment: var store = require('app-store-scraper');

var data = store.search({
  term: 'coffee',
  num: 10,
  page: 1,
});

Comment: And this is from the manual page of app-store-scraper!

Comment: `store.search({ term: 'coffee', num: 10, page: 1, }).then(data => { ... })`

Comment: Oh, now it works! Thank you :)